# Finding all numbers that evenly divide a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, helper

So I'm trying to make a program that when I input a number it will give me all the factors(`12`->`1,2,3,4,6,12`). I only started programming very recently so there may be some very obvious things. But here's my code

```
numbers = [1]
newnum = 1
chosen = int(input("Enter what you want the factors of: "))
def factors(numbers,newnum,chosen): 
    lastnum = numbers[-1]
    if (chosen == lastnum):
        for number in numbers:
            if (number % 1 != 0):
                numbers.remove(number)
                print (numbers)
            else:
                factors(numbers,newnum,chosen)
    else:
        newnum = numbers[-1] + 1
        numbers.append(newnum)
        print (numbers)
        factors(numbers,newnum,chosen)

factors(numbers,newnum,chosen)
```

Ok, so I don't really need the redundancies addressed but if you see something that would completely stop the program from working please point it out. Sorry I bothered you all with this but I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that actually contains information about the problem you're having or question you're asking. The title should be clear and descriptive enough to be useful to a future reader who sees it in a set of search results. Your current title contains nothing useful or descriptive. *I don't know what's wrong* is wasted space; clearly if you **did** know what was wrong, you wouldn't need to be posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of problems:

- Every integer number modulo 1 is zero because each integer is divisible by one without remainder.
- You remove items from the list you're iterating over, that will definetly give wrong results if you don't do it carefully!
- You try to do recursion but you don't return the result of the recursive call. That's possible because you operate on a mutable list but it's generally not really good style
- You don't have any inline comments explaining what that line is supposed to do, so it's hard to give any reasonable guidance on how to improve the code.

If you want a code that finds all factors, consider something like this:

```
chosen = int(input("Enter what you want the factors of: "))

def factors(chosen, currentnum=None, numbers=None): 
    # Recursion start, always append 1 and start with 2
    if numbers is None:
        numbers = [1]
        currentnum = 2
    # We're at the last value, it's always divisible by itself so
    # append it and return
    if currentnum == chosen:
        numbers.append(currentnum)
        return numbers
    else:
        # Check if the chosen item is divisible by the current number
        if chosen % currentnum == 0:
            numbers.append(currentnum)
        # Always continue with the next number:
        currentnum += 1
        return factors(chosen, currentnum, numbers)


>>> factors(chosen)
Enter what you want the factors of: 12
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12]
```

That's not the optimal solution but it uses recursion and gives a proper result. Just don't enter negative values or catch that case in the function at the beginning!

Comment: Wow, thanks man. Sorry for the trouble, I didn't think you would have to remake the entire program from step one.

Answer (score 0):

```
    # Two Pointer Approach

     ans = []
     
     
     def divisor(val):
         result = []
     
         for i in range(1, val + 1):
             ans.append(i)
     
         i = 0
         j = len(ans) - 1
     
         while i < j:
     
             if ans[i] * ans[j] == ans[-1]:
                 result.append(ans[i])
                 result.append(ans[j])
                 i += 1
             else:
                 j -= 1
     
         return sorted(result)
     
     
     print(divisor(12))


# Output

>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.